# Robot Framework integration with VSTS

Tags: python, visual-studio, robotframework

The company I recently joined is heavy into microsoft tools and products: Azure cloud, C#, Visual Studio, VSTS.....

As an automation engineer i have to setup a CI test environment on VSTS, Visual Studio Team Services. I wish to be able to run CI tests wth the Robat framework.

Is there an VSTS extension for Robot framework ?

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

[VS Robot Framework Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vivainio.robotframework)

Install it using:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

```
ext install robotframework
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Goralight. I did not realize you were talking about an extended requests library. I have just installed it....and lets see how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: @SandeepVaidya, Glad to help :)

Comment: Have you used this library?
In the 

Create Client OAuth2 Session    client    https://token    key    secret    base_url=https://service

What is "https://token"? 
We do not have a token server. Authentication is via OAUTH2 with credentials being supplied to the /v1/authtoken endpoint. 
Subsequent calls to the APÍ need to have the token included as a ‘bearer’ in the ‘Authorization’ header of the http requests.

Comment: I don't us VS - for anything. I don't understand why its asking you for tokens or anything though. Its basically a simple extension, just like any IDE will allow a install of. What exactly happens if you do the above steps? Does it error out? if so what error, etc.

Comment: This is how I am able to obtain the access token with the RequestsLibrary:
${data}=      Create Dictionary     grant_type=client_credentials     client_id=yyy-zzzz     client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ${headers}=   Create Dictionary      Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 ${resp}=  post request    hook   /v1/authtoken    data=${data}   headers=${headers}

However, when I use http://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/v1/authtoken as the parameter for token server url, the error is:
Post Request with client creds   |FAIL|
MissingTokenError: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter